# Sweetalert2 confirmbutton and paypal

Tags: forms, button, paypal, action, sweetalert2

I am trying to make the confirm button of [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) a "buy it now" paypal button (generated from my paypal account), is this possible?

The form looks like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="*********">
<input type="image" src="https://****.button.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I found the "window.location.href" but this is not a solution...

Below is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweet_alert_2/example.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/es6-promise/latest/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script> 
<script src="sweet_alert_2/sweetalert2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweet_alert_2/sweetalert2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sweet_alert_2/animate.css">

<button style="margin:auto;display:block" onclick="function()">BUY NOW !</button>

<script>
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
 swal({
  type: 'question',
  title: 'Do you want to buy it?',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'YES!',
  cancelButtonText: 'NO..'
}).then(function () {
    !!!!! HERE I WANT TO PUT PAYPAL !!!!!
  }, function (dismiss) {
  if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
  }
})
 };
</script>
```

Comment: see if this link helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18178509/2225030

Comment: Do you know how to implement it?